# Merging the two datasets

Tags: sas, proc-sql

```
Dataset A:

Company_Name Match Sales EMPS
1234         0     0     0
1234         0     0     0
1234         0     0     0
5678         0     0     0
5678         0     0     0
5678         0     0     0
9123         9123  500   2
9123         9123  500   2
9123         9123  500   2

Dataset B:

Company_Name Match Sales EMPS
    1234     1234    600   10  
    1234     1234    600   10    
    1234     1234    600   10     
    5678     5678    900   56
    5678     5678    900   56
    5678     5678    900   56
```

I am trying to merge the above tables using proc sql, and here is the desired output

```
Dataset A:

Company_Name Match Sales EMPS
    1234     1234    600   10  
    1234     1234    600   10    
    1234     1234    600   10     
    5678     5678    900   56
    5678     5678    900   56
    5678     5678    900   56
    9123     9123    500   2
    9123     9123    500   2
    9123     9123    500   2
```

However, when I try to do a join, it only takes the first table's values. I know I should do a case statement somewhere, but not sure how. For example, since datasetb had values for company_name=1234, the final output should capture that, and if there are no values, it should take the column values of the first table, if that makes sense

```
proc sql;
create table merge_table as
select a.*,b* from dataseta as a inner join datasetb as b on (a.company_name=b.company_name);quit;
```

Comment: You seem to have multiple observations for the same value of COMPANY_NAME. How do you want to match the multiple observations in each dataset in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the COALESCE() function to code your preference for B values over A value.

```
create table merge_table as
  select a.company_name
       , coalesce(b.match,a.match) as match
       , coalesce(b.sales,a.sales) as sales
       , coalesce(b.EMPS,a.EMPS) as EMPS
  from dataseta as a 
    inner join datasetb as b
    on (a.company_name=b.company_name)
;
```

But your example has repeats for COMPANY_NAME in both datasets. How do you want to handle that?  Currently it will match each of the three records from A for company 1234 with each of the three records from B for company 1234 and produce 9 records for that company in the result set. You need some other variable(s) to include in the join condition so that a performs a 1 to 1 match  (or at least a 1 to N match) instead of the current N to M match.

Comment: @Parfait  Good point. But note that the zero are only appearing in the dataset whose values are being overridden.  Original poster should supply more representative data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming same number of zero rows and non-zero rows to replace, consider a `union` query to stack non-zeros and other dataset:

```sql
proc sql;
create table merge_table as   
  select b.Company_Name, b.Match, b.Sales, b.EMPS
  from datasetb as b

  union

  select a.Company_Name, a.Match, a.Sales, a.EMPS 
  from dataseta as a 
  where (a.Match + a.Sales + a.EMPS) ^= 0; 
quit;
```